# Stokes's law proportionality to radius

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, dimensional-analysis, viscosity, navier-stokes

Is there a logical explanation why [Stokes's drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes's_law)

$F_d=6\pi R \eta v$

is proportional to the radius, $R$ of the sphere?

Naively I would have expected that it is proportional to the cross section, i.e. to $R^2$.

Comment: If the force solely depends on viscosity, velocity, and sphere geometry, what does dimensional analysis tell you about the required exponent of R?

Comment: @ChesterMiller: Well, yes. But how do I know that it depends on these quantities (only)?

Comment: You asked how it depends on R and not R^2, so I answered in that context.  What other parameters do you think might be involved?  Do you know how to do dimensional analysis using the Buckingham Pi Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in section 2.3 of this document by Lagree.

[Small Re flows](http://www.lmm.jussieu.fr/~lagree/COURS/M2MHP/petitRe.pdf)

Essentially the drag on the sphere is given by $F_d = 6\pi R \eta v$ because the boundary conditions on the velocity at the surface of the sphere and at infinity ensure that pressure and shear stress scales as $1/r^2$. When the pressure and shear stress are integrated over the surface of the sphere, one finds that the drag force will scale with $R$, the radius of the sphere.

Comment: This answer summarises the derivation of Stokes' Law but IMO it does not give any insight why the result is different for low and high Reynolds Number.

Comment: @sammygerbil unless i missed an edit, i didn't think an explanation for high Re was included in the question.

Comment: For high Re drag is proportional to area, as per user's intuition. User is asking for insight why that intuition does not hold the same for low Re.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this alternate form of Stokes drag:
$$F_d=6\pi\mu Rv=6\pi\mu \frac{v}{R}R^2 \sim \tau_w A$$
where $\tau_w\sim\mu \frac{v}{R}\propto R^{-1}$ is roughly the magnitude of the shear stress at the surface of the sphere and $A\propto R^{2}$ is the surface area of the sphere.

Clearly, its an algebraic combination of the shear stress and surface area which leads to a linear dependence on $R$.

Comment: Not clear. Where does $C_d \sim Re^{-1}$ come from? Isn't that just saying $F_d \propto R$ without explanation, which is what the question asks for?

Comment: I think the user is asking for intuition, physical insight. In your edit I can understand $\tau=F/A$ but I don't get why $\tau \sim \mu\frac{v}{R}$.

Comment: @sammygerbil - shear stress is defined as $\tau_w = -\mu\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}_w$, given that $v$ and $R$ are the characteristic velocity and length scales it follows that by approximation $\tau_w \sim \mu\frac{v}{R}$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I had forgotten about the velocity gradient. I do like your approximation $\frac{v}{R}$. I am not sure that the first part of your answer (for large Re) is actually needed.